# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0 running Core 2.0 App on Azure

Tags: azure, f#, .net-core

I developed a simple F# Suave application hosted in a console, using VS Code.

Target framework is core 2.0 and runs fine locally. The code is built and packaged (with references to `System.Runtime 4.3.0`) by VSTS and then deployed to an Azure App Service.

When I call the website it will eventually time out with HTTP 500, meanwhile `suave*.log` are written with the exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

- I did not change framework from 1.1 or 2.0, cleaned wwwroot anyhow
- Tried assembly redirects in web.config and app.config

Does this mean some package still references 4.2.0.0? 
Is Azure in the wrong?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio? What's the result if you deploy the project to Azure through Visual Studio directly? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? What are tasks of VSTS build and release definitions? Can you share the detail VSTS build and release log on the OneDrive?

Comment: I have VS but can’t publish the project because it is an consoleapp; everything is done by VSTS. I have not yet tried reproducing this with a new project, that’ll need some time to setup. In the meantime I do have to buildsteps and logs on a onedrive: [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Am4uFM2Lpd-ZhMseln0UIAQP32Refw)

Comment: Could you run that application through dotnet command (dotnet xxx.dll)? If so, you can download the artifact from build, then run it and check the result. On the other hand, to do test with a new project can narrow down the issue.

Comment: This hasn’t been resolved yet, although I found out some more; on the outside it looks like System.Runtime 4.3.0.0 is referenced (In the packages directory, in the IDE) but when inspecting de compiled dll, the reference is 4.2.0.0. I found a link (https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/730) describing similar problems but solutions used there haven’t solved my problem yet.
The next thing I wanna try is deploying an F# AspNetCore app using Suave, but the Suave.AspNetCore packages doesn’t support .Net Core 2.0 yet I think. I’m reconsidering my whole stack here…

Comment: Can you run the app through dotnet command?

Comment: Yes it just works. I'm starting to think the Suave package it causing it because I've created an F# AspNetCore app that worked but stopped working with the same error as soon Suave came in to play. I've looked into the SAFE-Stack example and the difference seems to be docker container vs mine web app.

Comment: Do you use the build files in build artifact for dotnet command?

Comment: Yes downloaded from vsts

Comment: So, it means the issue is in Azure.

Comment: That's what it looks like, but I can't say I 100% sure yet

Comment: The deploy task in release just copy the files to the azure app service. You can download the files from azure app service and run dotnet command and check the result. (`https://[app name].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`)

Comment: By default the files are in site\wwwroot folder.

Comment: That still works, so the questions is how to tell Azure to run this correct? I've already checked the dotnet version command on Kudu and it says 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error by creating and Self-contained deployment (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) although I'm not convinced this the preferable solution.